# have waterfall scaled plotly R

Tags: r, plotly, waterfall

I have the following data:

```
df = structure(list(x = structure(1:9, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), class = "factor"), 
measure = c("relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", 
"relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "total"), 
text = c("9184", "0", "0", "3153", "-1364", "-979", "-140", 
"0", "9508"), y = c(9184, 0, 0, 3153, -1364, -979, -140, 
0, 9508)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

and am making a waterfall, but want the values to start at a reasonable value, not 0, as there is a lot of empty space, and is not pleasing as shown below under A and I:

[image]

I would like it to start at like 6000 and tried to adjust my function by including `base = 6000`, as per https://plotly.com/r/waterfall-charts/ but that did not work.

[image]

Does anyone else have any suggestions.

my function for creating the fall is as follows:

```
plot_value_waterfall = function(df, name, type){
  rgb_total="rgb(0,0,255)"
  bridge_relation = ifelse(type == "3m", "Bridge 3m", "Bridge LTM")
  fig <- plot_ly(
    df, name = "Company 1", type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
    x = ~x, textposition = "outside", y= ~y, text =~text,
    connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)"))) 
  fig <- fig %>%
    layout(title = paste(name,bridge_relation),
           xaxis = list(title = ""),
           yaxis = list(title = ""),
           autosize = TRUE,
           showlegend = FALSE)
  
  fig %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(tickangle = 45),
           shapes = list(
             list(type = "rect",
                  fillcolor = rgb_total, 
                  line = list(color = rgb_total), 
                  opacity = 1,
                  x0 = -0.4, x1 = 0.4, xref = "x",
                  y0 = 0.0, y1 = df$y[1], yref = "y"),
             list(type = "rect",
                  fillcolor = rgb_total, 
                  line = list(color = rgb_total), 
                  opacity = 1,
                  x0 = dim(df)[1] - 1 - 0.4, x1 = dim(df)[1] - 1 + .4, xref = "x",
                  y0 = 0.0, y1 = df$y[dim(df)[1]], yref = "y")
           ))   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I've captured exactly what you have set out to do. I feel like what you wrote in your question says something entirely different than what you coded.
If I understand correctly, you want to change the range on the y-axis....literally. (If I've misunderstood, let me know.)

From the code in your question, I extracted your plot and added a specific y-axis range.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(
  df, name = "Company 1", type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
  x = ~x, textposition = "outside", y= ~y, text =~text,
  connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)"))) %>%
  layout( # title = paste(name,bridge_relation),
    xaxis = list(title = ""),
    yaxis = list(title = "", range = c(6000, 12900)),  # <---- defined range!
    autosize = TRUE,
    showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Kat. I am new to waterfalls, and was trying to find that range option for ages!